# java.rmi.ConnectIOException

Tags: java, rmi

I was currently reading the Head First Java book and went through the RMI chapter. I copied everything exactly as it is in the book, but I still have problems with this RMI thing.

This is the stack trace of the error.

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 192.168.0.110; nested exception is: 
    java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:632)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at MyRemoteImpl.main(MyRemoteImpl.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 6 more
```

I don't really know what it means, so here it is.

If you need anything else, ask and be answered.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `RMI` problem. It signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the remote host cannot be reached because of an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate router is down.

See javadocs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/NoRouteToHostException.html)

This has happened because you have copied the example word by word. You must replace `192.168.0.110` with a real, working host address.

This line in the trace:

```
at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
```

shows it is the `Naming.rebind()` method which has failed to work with that IP address. Please check the server code and put the correct IP address there. If it is not in the code itself, please also look for it inside the configuration files.

Comment: But I'm trying to connect to the localhost (127.0.0.1). Does the firewall trouble it as well?

Comment: In the trace it is shown you are trying to connect to: 192.168.0.110!

Comment: But the line I wrote is as follows.
MyRemote service = (MyRemote) Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1/remotehello");
Nowhere did I write the address in the stack trace. Could it be, by chance, a configuration of rmiregistry?

Comment: Then, I am skeptical of the Naming look up call. Where is the `RMI Registry` itself running?

Comment: If you mean the machine, it's the same I'm working on. I tried replacing 127.0.0.1 with localhost, but that was of no use. I start the RMI Registry on one terminal and execute the file on another.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17989/discussion-between-reza-goodarzi-and-patrick-villela)

Comment: I changed Naming.rebind("remotehello", service) to Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/remotehello", service). I could run MyRemoteImpl, but I went up to the same problem to run MyRemoteClient, although the addresses are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time is the reason for the firewall, you can try to close the firewall to confirm the cause

```
service iptables stop
```